# grep with variable numbers of whitespaces

Tags: linux, grep

I want to grep for a string which I know exists in my files. However, the source it comes from managed to change the number of whitespaces so that the content per se is identical in the string, but the length differs. => ordinary grep does not find it. Is there a way to adjust for it?

I dont's see a system behind the additional whitespace effect

Here's the original string

```
4FD0-A tr|A5ZLA0|A5ZLA0_9BACE Bacterial
```

and here's the modified string

```
4FD0-A    tr|A5ZLA0|A5ZLA0_9BACE Bacterial
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that egrep would be your friend here. Try the following command:

```
egrep  '4FD0-A\s+tr[|]A5ZLA0[|]A5ZLA0_9BACE\s+Bacterial'  filename
```

I used a rather simple pattern for my example. Feel free to change it to suit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "one or more" `+` operator. For example

```
grep '^4FD0-A\s\+tr|' myfile
```

The `\s` searches for any whitespace. If you want to limit it to only spaces just use a single space in place of the `\s`

Answer (score 0):

You can use all kind of utilities for deleting spaces.
Try this:

```
cat file |tr -s '\ ' | grep '4FD0-A tr|A5ZLA0|A5ZLA0_9BACE Bacterial'
```